# Craft/micro brewery in Saarland, Luxembourg and Lorraine region?

Tags: breweries, german-beers, micropub

I found these [Beer from Saarland](http://www.ratebeer.com/state/saarland/122/) but it looks more like commercial brews.

Are there any craft/microbrewery in the tri-country greater region of Saarland (Germany), Luxembourg and Lorraine (France)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all... you must know in this regions there is a laarge tradition with beer, so microbreweries are not as usual as in other regions, because there is a lot of abbeys and old factories that made beer in a traditional way. That tradition gives us really good beers, what makes microbreweries less usual than in other regions like Spain or Italy or center-south part of France where *comercial* beers are a real shit ;).

That's why I will make not only a microbreweries list, but also places where you can find craft and traditional beers of each region.

Also, feel free to check [this map I made](https://www.google.es/maps/@48.4516656,8.0454995,8z/data=!4m2!6m1!1szrzqQBPCMC1M.kqh_EIttyqVc?hl=es) where you can find some Bretagne (France), Flandes (Belgium) and some Italian (Roma), Home/micro-breweries, Abbeys, Factories, Brasseurs and Bars :) related.

## Saarland

[Here](http://www.europeanbeerguide.net/saarbrew.htm#breweries) and [here](http://www.ratebeer.com/breweries/saarland/122/79/) you can find more Saarland breweries.

**Walsheimer Sudhaus Microbrewery**
walsheimer-sudhaus.de
Facebook: walsheimbrauerei
info@walsheim-brauerei.de

**Neufang's Brauerei**
Dudweiler Landstraße 3-9,
66123 Saarbrücken.
http://www.neufang.de/

**Grosswald Brauerei - Bauer**
Grosswaldstrasse 132,
66265 Heusweiler.
http://www.grosswald.de

**Hochwälder Braugasthaus**
Zum Stausee 190,
66679 Losheim am See.
http://hochwaelder-brauhaus.de/

**Homburger Brauhaus Karl-Heinz Wierz Saarpfalz-Center**
Talstraße 38,
66424 Homburg.
http://www.homburger-brauhaus.de

## Luxembourg

[Here](http://www.europeanbeerguide.net/luxbrew.htm#breweries) and [here](http://www.ratebeer.com/places/city/luxembourg/0/122/) you can find more Luxembourg breweries.

**Brasserie Simon** 
rue Joseph Simon 14,
9550 Wiltz.
Homepage: http://www.brasseriesimon.lu/
Annual production: 23,000 hl

**Brasserie Bofferding** 
Bd J.F. Kennedy 2,
4901 Bascharage.
Email: direction@bofferding.lu
Homepage: http://www.bofferding.lu/

**Go Ten Café**
Type: Bar (6 taps, 8 bottles)
10, rue du Marché-aux-Herbes
Luxembourg, Luxembourg L-1728   
+352 26203652
www.goten.lu

**Liquid Café**
Type: Bar (6 taps 25 bottles)
15 - 17, rue Munster, Grund
Luxembourg, Luxembourg
+352224455
www.liquid.canalblog.com

## Lorraine

Finde [here a list of breweries and brewers](http://www.ratebeer.com/breweries/france/0/72/) (is a France one, but you can search for cities like Metz) and here a list of [brasseurs](http://www.ratebeer.com/brewers/les-brasseurs-de-lorraine/4265/) (traditional beer producers in france).

**Bière de Metz**
Rue de la Fontaine à l Auge
Jury, France 57245
(3) 87 63 83 41

**Bière Artisanale Lorraine L’Epitaphe**
40, rue de France
Blénod-Lès-Pont-À-Mousson, France 54700